# R netWorkD3 Sankey - add percentage by js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I'm creating a sankey chart in R with `networkD3::sankeyNetwork()` with the below sample data and script. I want to show percentage besides the node label.

the sankey with full dataset i create has 8 layers. i just post piece of data in below code.

```
library("networkD3")
library("htmlwidgets")
library("dplyr")

a <- read.csv(header = TRUE, text = "
date,dataCenter,customer,companyID,source,target,value

")

node_names <- unique(c(as.character(a$source), as.character(a$target)))
nodes <- data.frame(name = node_names)
links <- data.frame(source = match(a$source, node_names) - 1,
                    target = match(a$target, node_names) - 1,
                    value = a$value)

# group by source and calculate the percentage of each node
g <- a %>%
  group_by(source) %>%
  summarize(cnt = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = round(cnt / sum(cnt) * 100, 2)) %>%
  arrange(desc(freq))


nodes$name <- sub('(.*)_\\d+', '\\1', nodes$name)
links$linkgroup <- "linkgrp"
colourScale <- 
  'd3.scaleOrdinal()
     .domain(["linkgrp"])
     .range(["gainsboro"].concat(d3.schemeCategory20))'

p <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              fontSize = 9,
              fontFamily = "sans-serif", nodePadding=10,
              margin = list(t=100),
              sinksRight = FALSE, iterations = 0,
              LinkGroup = "linkgroup", 
              colourScale = colourScale)

showLabel_string <- 
  'function(el, x){
    d3.select(el).selectAll(".node text")
      .text(d => d.name + " (" + d.value + ")");}'

addTitle_string <-
  'function(el) { 
    var cols_x = this.sankey.nodes().map(d => d.x+15).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i).sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    cols_x.forEach((d, i) => {
    d3.select(el)
    .select("svg")
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", d)
    .attr("y", 0).text("step" + (i + 1))
    .style("font-size", "12px")
    .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .style("text-orientation", "upright");})
  }'

p <- htmlwidgets::onRender(x = p, jsCode = showLabel_string)
p <- htmlwidgets::onRender(x = p, jsCode = addTitle_string)
p <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(p, htmltools::tags$h3("Opportunity Marketing User Behavior Monitor"))
p
```

Now I want to show the percentage besides each node label and count. I have already calculate the percentage value by below scirpt, but how to put it after node label and count?

I realize that below way to calculate the percentage for each node is not correct because when grouping by 'source' column, the nodes  in last layer are missed as they are working as 'target' nodes only. I update the expected result with a new picture in the post which is more clear for how the percentage shown. In general, the percentage should follow the conservation of energy. Is it possible to achieved?

```
g <- a %>%
  group_by(source) %>%
  summarize(cnt = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = round(cnt / sum(cnt) * 100, 2)) %>%
  arrange(desc(freq))
```

Expected Result is
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add variables to the `nodes` data.frame *after* the htmlwidget is created (otherwise, `sankeyNetwork()` will only keep the required columns). Then you can edit the custom code for the text of the node labels to include the percentage...

```r
p$x$nodes <- g %>% 
  mutate(name = sub("_[0-9]", "", source)) %>% 
  select(name, freq) %>% 
  right_join(p$x$nodes, by = "name") %>% 
  mutate(freq = ifelse(is.na(freq), "", paste0(freq, "%")))

showLabel_string <- 
  'function(el, x){
    d3.select(el).selectAll(".node text")
      .text(d => d.name + " (" + d.value + ") " + d.freq);}'
```

[image]

Comment: Hi CJ - Thanks a lot. But when i tried your solution with the full dateset in local, the percentage displayed are not expected.  Then I tried with the sample data and observe that the percentage only shows for first layer, there's no percentage shown for the nodes in second layer.  After revisit my code, I realize that the way to calculate the percentage  is not correct because when grouping by 'source' column, the nodes  in last layer are missed as they are working as 'target' nodes only. I update the expected result with a new picture in the post. Is it able to achieved?

Comment: You can add whatever values you want to the nodes data frame, then refer to them in JavaScript. So, figure out what percentages you want to be shown, then just add them to the p$x$nodes and it should work